# Read multiline value in ANTLR untill a special symbol occurs

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

How can i read a multiline text in ANTLR untill a special symbol occurs. Like as in below text:-

```
@Description("
Hi There I am.
")
```

I need to read it as **key -> @Description** and  **value -> "Hi There I am"**.

I tried it with following grammar

```
KEY
 : '@' [a-zA-Z] (~[(\r\n] | '\\)')*
 ;


VALUE
 : '(' ~[\r\n]*
 ;
```

I tried many variations of VALUE grammar but no luck.

Comment: The VALUE rule looks strange. Have a look at lexer modes or don't try to solve it with two lexer rules  only(i.e. add parser rules also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely confused by the lexer/parser separation here. You did only provide a single example, but I can infer the following:

```
declaration: KEY '(' STRING ')' ;
KEY : '@' [a-zA-Z]+ ;
STRING: '"' (~'"')* '"' ;
WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

`declaration` is a parser rule. It consists of a `KEY` (`@` followed by letters), an opening parenthesis, a `STRING` (any text between quotes), and a closing parenthesis. `KEY` and `STRING` are the lexer rules.

Be aware that the `STRING` rule above won't let you escape characters. If you need to be able to escape a quote with a backslash (and also a backslash with a backslash), use the following rule instead:

```
STRING: '"' ('\\' ["\\] | ~'"')* '"'
```